# scrolling custom UITableView slow

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am facing the following problem :

I have a custom UITableView with each cell having an image with some text. When, I scroll the UITable, for each section, the respective image will be shown on top of the UITable.

The scrolling is little slow and seems to be sticky.

Can anyone give me any idea how to improve this ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample code from apple on lazy image loading: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html
I think that will help you a lot... You also need to watch for reusing cells properly..

Comment: customCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];     --- am using this....anything else to look out for in reusing cells properly ?

Comment: it should be all.. if using xib file as cell then you should set identifier in xib properties and you should be good to go...

Answer (score 0):

if U have too many subviews in cell，it must be slow when scrolling，apple says it。

Comment: in my cell subview, I have 1 UIImageView, 3 UILabel and 1 UIImage as separator .... I do have a lot of cells though.... Also, the images included are very small and I do download all the images at the starting.